# WebStorm + ReactNative?

Tags: webstorm, react-native

Is it possible to debug ReactNative code from WebStorm? ReactNative allows debug from Chrome/Safari, maybe WebStorm could use these ports for debugging from IDE somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html), there's **no way** to do it *right now*.

Why? Because when using "Debug in Chrome," you're actually running *all your Javascript code* **inside of Chrome**! The native app simply *pulls* all the data from Chrome via **websocket**.

So to implement React Native debugging in WebStorm, it seems like you'll need to come up with either of the following:

1. A way to run your JS code inside of WebStorm, passing the data to the native app via websocket.
2. A way to modify React Native's Chrome-side code to allow WebStorm to connect to it, like GDB would to a C application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is interesting, but how WebStorm supports debugging of web javascript then?

Comment: Seems 0.25.1 allows third-party debuggers now https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/4c8a9f0d00cfb452a03077d914e6accb94a9769b

Comment: Looks like Webstorm now supports react-native debugging! Details here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/10/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6512/

Comment: this answer is no longer up to date.

Answer (score 12):

With the new 2016.3 EAP of WebStorm and as well IDEA you can now debug react-native apps:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/10/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6512/

Comment: Do you know of a way to run on a different port than 8081?